# when does stack exhaust when javascript call recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I know this function makes error because stack exhaust while calling self function.

```
function loop() {
    loop();
}
```

And I want to make callback function that is calling self function

first:

```
var load_function = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve()
});

function loop() {
    load_function.then(
    function() {
        loop();
    }).catch(
    function() {
        loop();
    });
}
```

second:

```
function loop() {
    setTimeout(loop, 3);
}
```

And these function does not makes error.

Is it safe to use these function in infinity loop call?

Comment: Both of these involve callbacks that are queued into the call stack *after* the current call stack is emptied instead of indefinitely adding to the call stack.

Comment: Note that since `load_function` is a single promise, not a function, the result of you loop will be calling `then()` over and over again on the same promise. A promise will only resolve once.

Comment: If you recursively calling any function, this will automatically stop after sometime.

Comment: I think stack may be emptied when function loop reach end although callback left